# How can I remove leading whitespace in my <pre>/<code> block without removing indentation in my HTML?

Tags: html, css, pre

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
    Here is some code:

    <pre><code>
        Here is some fun code!    
    </code></pre>
</body>
```

But when I preview it, because the code is indented, the pre is all out of whack. I can fix that by bringing the contents back against the indent, but it looks silly. Can I make that above text look non-indented?

Comment: Is that what you want [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwypjea6/1/) ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki If I'm reading the question correctly, that's what we want visually, but without having to remove the indentation from the markup.

Comment: What's happening is kinda what the `pre` tag is for...

Comment: Not *really*, the contents of the `<body>` tag aren't indented.

Comment: Maybe a picture of exactly what you want would help us help you...

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: You can add `pre{margin-left: -55px;}` to fix it's position. Advantage: minimum code to add. Disadvantage: it's a bypass and it is needed to be changed in every particular case. I like the `<!-- -->` way that Paul Roub have mentioned above. Both do not require any JS code.

Comment: Another Solution in case anyone is curious is to set the pre tags line-height to 0px. For example <pre style="line-height: 0px"></pre> That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 32):

You could try this maybe:

```
pre, code{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwypjea6/2/)

Comment: I upvoted, because it works. Set `<pre>`'s white-space to normal, but `<code>`'s white-space should be `pre`.

Comment: It worked for me!.  `white-space: normal;` removes all the spaces. I had to use `white-space: pre-line;` as that removed only the spaces from the beginning.

Answer (score 13):

Here you go, I decided to come up with something more concrete than changing the way `pre` or `code` work. So I made some regex to get the first newline character `\n` (preceded with possible whitespace - the `\s*` is used to cleanup extra whitespace at the end of a line of code and before the newline character (which I noticed yours had)) and find the tab or whitespace characters following it `[\t\s]*` (which means tab character, whitespace character (0 or more) and set that value to a variable. That variable is then used in the regex replace function to find all instances of it and replace it with `\n` (newline). Since the second line (where `pattern` gets set) doesn't have the global flag (a `g` after the regex), it will find the first instance of the `\n` newline character and set the `pattern` variable to that value. So in the case of a newline, followed by 2 tab characters, the value of `pattern` will technically be `\n\t\t`, which will be replaced where every `\n` character is found in that `pre code` element (since it's running through the each function) and replaced with `\n`

```js
$("pre code").each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    var pattern = html.match(/\s*\n[\t\s]*/);
    $(this).html(html.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"),'\n'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Here is some code:

    <pre><code>
        Here is some fun code!
        More code
          One tab
            One more tab
            
            Two tabs and an extra newline character precede me
    </code></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Works very well, I've wrote a ES6 version without jQuery if sb. needs it https://gist.github.com/wintersolutions/4f3471954db73bf2d8f4e0ab541cf724

Answer (score 2):

This works, assuming indentation should be based on the first line of code:

```js
//get the code element:
var code= document.querySelector('pre code');

//insert a span in front of the first letter.  (the span will automatically close.)
code.innerHTML= code.textContent.replace(/(\w)/, '<span>$1');       

//get the new span's left offset:
var left= code.querySelector('span').getClientRects()[0].left;      

//move the code to the left, taking into account the body's margin:
code.style.marginLeft= (-left + code.getClientRects()[0].left)+'px';
```

```css
code {
  display: block;  //this is necessary for the JavaScript to work properly
}
```

```html
<body>
    Here is some code:

    <pre><code>
        Here is some fun code!    
          And some more!
            Continuing
          Wrapping up
        Closing code now.
    </code></pre>
</body>
```