# How to ignore the n first tabulations in an XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt, indentation, pre

#### The situation

In my XML files, I could have peace of code to show inside the tag `<code>`. But the indentation of my XML document is in conflict with the tabulation inside the `<code>` section.

#### Minimal Working Example

###### The XML file

```xml
        <article>
            <code lang="c">
            #include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
            int main() {
                // printf() displays the string inside quotation
                printf("Hello, World!");
                return 0;
            }
            </code>
        </article>
```

###### The peace of XSLT

```
    <xsl:template match="code">
        <pre><xsl:value-of select="."/></pre>
    </xsl:template>
```

###### The expected HTML rendering

```html
<pre>   #include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
    int main() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}</pre>
```

##### Explanations

As you see, the goal is to ignore the *n* first tabulations and the *n* last tabulation (if any) inside the tags, when *n* is equal to the number of tabulation before the opening tag `<code>`. And also to ignore the first new line, and the last new line (the one just before the tabulations before the closing `</code>` tag).

##### More explanations

According to @michael.hor257k suggestion to bring more clarifications, in other terms, the XSLT style sheet should treat the XML `<code>` part shown above like if it was like this:

```xml
        <article>
            <code lang="c">#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
int main() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}</code>
        </article>
```

As you see the tabs bellonging to the XML indentation should not be included in the final HTML `<pre>` tag.

In more graphical way, we can say that the tabs corresponding to the tabs commented bellow should be ignored in the processing:

```xml
        <article>
            <code lang="c"><!--
         -->#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
<!--     -->int main() {
<!--     -->    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
<!--     -->    printf("Hello, World!");
<!--     -->    return 0;
<!--     -->}<!--
         --></code>
        </article>
```

An this spaces, tabs, and new lines are corresponding to the XML indentation and not to the internal C code indentation.

##### Conclusion — Question

So, is it possible in my XSLT to parse the number of tabs before the opening `<code>` tag in order to delete them from the beginning of each content’s line?

Comment: Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754419/ would be easier?

Comment: Well @MartinHonnen it’s corrected now. I just quickly take the first hello word example I found without looking what he contain. However, it’s not the main subject.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your requirement. I believe you can find out the indent of `code` by looking at the first text node that is child of `article` (provided your stylesheet does not strip whitespace). How you intend to use that is not clear to me. This seems like an [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/). --- P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I use currently `xsltproc` how can I get the version of xslt it support with `--version`, I just get “Using libxml 20910, libxslt 10134 and libexslt 820
”.

Comment: xsltproc = libxslt = XSLT 1.0 (with considerable support for EXSLT extension functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try perhaps something like:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code">
    <xsl:variable name="indent" select="substring-after(preceding-sibling::text(), '&#10;')" />
    <pre>
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., '&#10;')[normalize-space()]">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., $indent)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </pre>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there are some assumptions here that your example satisfies, but other cases may not.